# Derive & Destroy Encapsulation, or Violate DRY?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, encapsulation

I have two C++ classes: `Sequence`, which is just like `std::vector`, and `File`, which is a `Sequence` of strings that represents a file on the machine.

Deriving `File` from `Sequence` is a no-brainer.  Its behavior is exactly the same, but with the added functionality of reading and writing files.  The `File`-specific functionality is implemented easily, without the need for `Sequence`'s data members to be marked as protected.  Instead, they can be private, and `File` can use `Sequence`'s public interface.  Happy times all around.

I want to make an `Array` class that internally manages dynamically-allocated memory.  An `Array` object cannot be resized; the size is specified in the constructor.*

Here's where things get arguable.

Concept-wise, it makes sense to derive `Sequence` from `Array`.  Just as a `File` is a `Sequence` with the added functionality of reading and writing files, `Sequence` is an `Array` with the added functionality of resizing on-demand.

But there's a key difference: The resizing functions require **direct access** to the memory `Array` is managing.  In other words, the previously-private members must now be protected.

Using protected members instead of private ones destroys encapsulation.  The link between `Array` and `Sequence` is the only one that requires it; other classes in the works can just use their parents' public interfaces.  In this sense, it's a bad idea to derive.

You could argue that people who want arrays can just use `Sequence` and ignore the resizing functionality.  But then again, you could just use `File` and ignore the read/write functionality.  It would be like buying a laptop but never moving it from your desk.  It simply doesn't make sense.

What's the best move: To derive, and potentially destroy encapsulation; to make `Array` a completely free-standing class, and have to pointlessly re-implement a lot of functionality; or to forget about `Array` completely and just make people use `Sequence`?

**Note that this is a project for fun and education, so the practicality of having a non-resizable dynamically-allocated array is beside the point.*

Comment: What is the relationship between "Array" and "Sequence"?  Your description of "Array" simply says that it is a class that internally manages dynamically-allocated memory (and yet it is of a fixed size...?)  It's not clear from that explanation why the two classes are related at all.

Comment: @Joseph I don't see how it's unclear.  `Array` just allocates space via `InternalArray = new T[SizeSpecifiedInConstructor]`.  `Sequence` does the exact same thing, but it also provides member functions to resize `InternalArray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, deriving `Sequence` from `Array` with **public** inheritance in your case is definitely bad idea (as deriving square from rectangle). In the terms of Object-Oriented Programming, Sequence **IS NOT** an Array, since `Array` has a property that `Sequence` does not have, and it's: `An Array object cannot be resized`. If you make a derivation, it will break the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

In your case, as you want to implement some functionality, already existing in another class, I would suggest you to use either **private** inheritance (which means inheritance of implementation), or **composition**, e.g. storing an instance of `Array` in private zone of `Sequence` and using it for inner implementation.

***UPD:*** However, implementing `Sequence` with usage of an `Array` also seems to me quite problematic. Maybe it would by much better to create some abstract base class `Container` that would implement the common functionality of `Sequence` and `Array`, and then derive both these classes from it.

Comment: How would it violate the LSP?  Remember, any function that operates on an `Array&` can safely do the same thing with a `Sequence&`.

Comment: This is different from the Square/Rectangle example, because nothing you can do to an `Sequence` will change the fact that it still behaves as an `Array` when treated as one, and vice versa.

Comment: You can change the size of the Sequence, can't you ? As soon as Sequence is an Array (by the meaning of public inheritance), this means that you are changing the size of an Array - contradiction with the Array's invariant

Comment: For example, you can have functions Array::check_validity(), which throws an exception if array's initial size has been currupted, and Sequence::push_back(), which adds element to the sequence and, of course, increases it's size. Then if you write the following code: Sequence s; s.push_back( x ); s.check_validity() - here you will get an exception, whether logic says that you were performing all operations on a Sequence, so everything should be ok.

Comment: @Grigor I think that's taking the LSP too far into a hypothetical scenario.  It doesn't make sense to give `Array` methods like `check_validity()` because there is simply no way it can be invalid.  While I do understand how it breaks `Array`'s invariant, it's not that an `Array` guarantees the size will not be changed, but rather that it provides no mechanisms to do so.  Besides, even if `Array` did have `check_validity()`, `Sequence` would definitely override it.

Comment: I take it back... It is like the square/rectangle example. In both cases, the issue only springs up if you design your interface such that it is a problem. Why would you ever write a "SizeHasChanged" method?

Comment: For the record, I do agree that public inheritance is inappropriate. I would consider deriving Array from Sequence privately if anything. Just not because of a LSP violation.

Comment: This example was hypothetical, just to show that there may be a scenario when this kind of public inheritance leads to undesired behaviour of program. @Maxpm: you could check the invariant of Array's size with non-member function also, and that way you couldn't override it. I'm sure it's pretty possible to construct an example that is much more closer to real world. The point is irrefutable - a Sequence is NOT an Array, which means using public inheritance is absolutely inopportunely.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider slicing the problem in a slightly different direction. Instead of inheritance, perhaps this problem could be solved with a template -- specifically, a policy template that manages a buffer for a collection. You'd have (at least) two implementations of that: one for fixed allocation, the other for automatically resizing.

That wouldn't break encapsulation at all, and nearly the only overlap I can see between the two would be that the initial allocation is probably about the same whether fixed or variable. Given how trivial that is, I doubt it's worth spending much time or effort on trying to factor it out. In theory it could be, but at least in a typical case we're talking about one line of code, and a pretty simple one at that.

Going back to the inheritance question for a moment, it comes down to this: this is very much like the standard circle vs. oval situation, where there's enough similarity for one to seem like the other, but ultimately neither satisfies the LSP -- you can't treat either one as the other safely, so (at least public) inheritance isn't suitable. Private inheritance doesn't require following LSP, but is generally only useful when/if you need/want to override a base class' virtual function, which seems unlikely here as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use derivation here.

A `Sequence` is not really an `Array`. While practically they appear to have a number of common methods, from a design point of view they have very different uses and guarantees.

It would make sense, though, to use an `Array` within the `Sequence`, and for `Sequence` to forward a number of calls (inline) to the `Array` directly:

```
template <typename T>
class Sequence
{
public:
  Sequence(): _array(10) {}
  explicit Sequence(size_t n): _array(n) {}

  bool empty() const { return _size == 0; }
  size_t size() const { return _size; }
  size_t capacity() const { return _array.size(); }

private:
  size_t _size; // current size
  Array<T> _array;
}; // class Sequence
```

*Note: I assumed here that the Array was built with all its elements at once, while the sequence will add them one at a time*

Similarly, does it make sense for a `File` to derive from a `Sequence` ? Don't you have implementation issues, like sync'ing the content of `Sequence` with the on-disk representation ?

Comment: I do not continuously sync the `File` object with the on-disk representation.  Instead, I provide methods like `Open()` and `Save()`.